# disposing realm in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using `Realm` in `Xamarin.Forms` to build mobile application and have some doubts related to closing the realm in xamarin.

Following is the method to update records in realm

```
public  void updateData(EventType e)
        {

               Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance();
                 realm.WriteAsync(tempRealm =>
                {

                    tempRealm.Add(e.response, true);
                });

                realm.Dispose();

                MessagingCenter.Send<IMessage, EventType>(this, RestApi.UI_EVENT, e);


        }
```

1. Do we need to call realm.Dispose() everytime whenever we call `Realm.GetInstance();` ?
2. Does WriteAsync takes care of closing/disposing realm ?
3. Do i have to use `await` againts `realm.WriteAsync` as its an asynchronous method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we need to call realm.Dispose() everytime whenever we call Realm.GetInstance?

Yes. Eventually you *should* `Dispose` on your Realm instances when you are not longer using them. This will release any consumed resources (native and managed).

*Typically* I keep a UI thread instance open during the life time of the app (following the application lifecycle for each platform). i.e. I treat this `Realm` instance like an `HttpClient` instance, an application level singleton that you can open additional instances from. Now I do open and dispose of instances on background threads when I am updating the database via services, broadcast receivers, push updates, etc...

Note: Remember if you are on a *background* thread and obtain multiple Realm instances of the same `RealmConfigurationBase` on that thread, they actually will all be the same Realm instance (`Realm.IsSameInstance`). You can call Dispose on each one and not actually *close* (`Realm.IsClosed`) the instance until all the *instances* on that thread are disposed of.

> Does WriteAsync takes care of closing/disposing realm?

Yes. You do not want to call `Dispose` on the Realm instance that is passed into your `WriteAsync` lamba function.

In fact if you do you will receive a `System.ObjectDisposedException` since Realm has wrapped that lamba with a transaction block and you have dispose the realm instance before the transaction has been committed or rolled back.

> Do i have to use await against realm.WriteAsync as its an asynchronous method.

Refer to the many other SOs regarding fire&forget async method calling, i.e.:  [Why do I have to use await for a method to run asynchronously. What if I don't want to wait for the method to finish before continuing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078849/why-do-i-have-to-use-await-for-a-method-to-run-asynchronously-what-if-i-dont-w)